# Prevent vertical scroll bars when displaying web page?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Hey im trying to to get my website so it doesn't scroll vertically and im struggling its now scrolling just a bit(20px max)

[Site is Here](http://22twenty.com/Final/)
Css: [css here](http://jsfiddle.net/8pNNK/)

Hope you can help

Denver

Answer (score 1):

Your `#container` div had a height of 100%. Below is your footer, which has some height as well. You should make your container less high or place your footer inside your container, so the total height of both elements below each other doesn't exceed 100%.

Comment: I believe it is inside the container?

Comment: i have set it in the container now no change:(

Answer (score 1):

You've got `body { padding-bottom: 20px; }`. Your box-model is set to the traditional CSS2.1 model, so its "height" is actually "100% + 20px". Eliminate the padding and you're set.

Comment: In firebug, removing `padding-bottom` alone is not enough. The footer has to be removed aswell. But +1 still.

Comment: Gah! Yes, you're right (although personally I prefer the DOM Inspector extension to Firebug, and after removing the 20px padding the page is still too tall, so you're right).